# How to retrieve Remote Database values into text box using C# in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#

Good Day!. I am trying for retrieving remote database values and showing into windows form text boxes.

I can able to retrieving only string values to text box. But could not retrieve integer values. How to retrieve integer values.

```
TabPage tpge = new TabPage();
tpge = tabControl1.SelectedTab;

SqlConnection cn = null;
string connectString = "";
SqlCommand cmd = null;
SqlDataReader rdr = default(SqlDataReader);

connectString = string.Format("Data Source = IP,1433;Initial Catalog=idb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD;");
cn = new SqlConnection(connectString);

try
{
    if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        cn.Open();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Open Error");
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
try
{
    MessageBox.Show("1");
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tAerator1", cn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        txtAEremrk.Text = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("fldAEremrk"));
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}

cn.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use the one of ExecuteReader's "GetInt" methods to return integer results.

**[GetInt16](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint16(v=vs.110).aspx)**

Gets the value of the specified column as a 16-bit signed integer. (Overrides DbDataReader.GetInt16(Int32).)

**[GetInt32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint32(v=vs.110).aspx)**

Gets the value of the specified column as a 32-bit signed integer. (Overrides DbDataReader.GetInt32(Int32).)

**[GetInt64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint64(v=vs.110).aspx)**

Gets the value of the specified column as a 64-bit signed integer. (Overrides DbDataReader.GetInt64(Int32).)

**Examples**

```
rdr.GetInt32(rdr.GetOrdinal("yourIntegerField"));
```

> I can able to retrieving only string values to text box. But could not
>   retrieve integer values. How to retrieve integer values.

Returning the integer value alone is not enough.  The textbox only accepts string values.  The ToString() method is also required to convert the returned integer value to a string.

```
txtAEremrk.Text  = rdr.GetInt32(rdr.GetOrdinal("yourIntegerField")).ToString()
```

Comment: Hi @Suji if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.